# Vector fields generating a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras, integrable-systems

It would be great if someone can explain to me what the following means:

> Vector fields $V_i, i=1,2,3$ generate 3 single-parameter groups of transformations in $\mathbb R$ -- $$\tilde x =x\exp(\alpha);$$$$\tilde x = x+\beta;$$$$ \tilde x = {x\over 1-\gamma x}$$ respectively. These 3 vector fields together generate a 3-parameter group of transformations: $\tilde x = {ax+b\over cx+d}$ where $ad-bc=1$

I think I understand the first bit, and I think the $V_i$'s are $x\partial_x; \partial_x;x^2\partial _x$ respectively. However, I have no clue what the second bit is talking about -- how do you combine them and why is that so?

---

Qiaochu has helpfully pointed out that this has to do with Lie algebra. Could anyone further explain how they combine these vector fields/transformations to give the 3-parameter transformation group?

Thank you.

---

Anyone?

Comment: The second bit asserts that three vector fields span a Lie algebra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) which generates a Lie group (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group).

Comment: Thank you, @QiaochuYuan , how though did they combine them to get that resulting transformation?